# Niveus and nivosus

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, adjective, derivation

I would like to compare the two adjectives *niveus* and *nivosus* derived from *nix*, "snow".
My prior understanding of these words was that *niveus* is "snow-white" and *nivosus* is "snowy", but [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=niveus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) tells me that also *niveus* means "snowy".

My guess is that *niveus* means that there is snow without commenting on the amount, whereas *nivosus* means that there is a lot of snow.
Is this guess correct?

Does some dictionary offer a comparison of these two adjectives?
Is there some example (artificial if original ones are not available) that contrasts *niveus* and *nivosus*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, the -*osus* ending indicates plenty. *Lacrimosa* isn't just "teary-eyed," but weepy. Same with *nivosa*. *Niveus* is often used with mountains to describe the snow-topped peaks, and from the quality of snow (i.e. whiteness), it is used to describe things in English we'd describe as "snow-white" - teeth, milk, togas, fleece (as in the old nursery rhyme). *Nivosa*, on the other hand, is used to describe places where there is a lot of snow - northern climates (Scythia is given as an example in L&S), wintry storms. You wouldn't describe your teeth as *nivosus* without some humorous characterization: face full of snow, perhaps, on account of a snowball.